# Add data in nested UL in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-lists

I have a multiple level nested UL for a Menu Control in my Asp.net (C#) website. Example list is given below:

```
   <ul class="my-menu">
    <li><a href="#a">My User Control Menu</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#aa">menu item that is quite long</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#ab">menu item</a>
                <ul>
                    <li ><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#aba">menu item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#abb">menu item</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">menu item 2</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">menu item 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">menu item</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">short</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">short</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">menu item 4</a> </li>
  </ul>
```

How can I add the elements in any nested order in my list through code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the menu using a repeater:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306154